# How to add all positive numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am using swi-prolog to ge the sum of all positive integers in a given list

So far this is my code, Kindly assist me with where im going wrong

```
sumPos([] ,0).
sumPos([Head | Tail], X) :- Head > 0,
    sumPos(Tail, N), 
    X is N+Head.
```

To test i am using

```
sumPos([1,-2,3,-5], X).
```

And the answer should be X=4 but i get false

Comment: Why do you insist that `Head > 0` when you have numbers like `-2`?

Comment: Thats to check if head is positive

Comment: But that's the reason it returns false. It checks `-2 > 0` and returns false obviously.

Comment: How can i properly check if its positive?

Comment: You only defines what happens for positive numbers but your test case contains negative ones (compare with `sumPos([1,2,3],X).` ). If there's no way to derive those your predicate will fail.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x there is no need for a check at all.

Comment: @TA_inter indeed :) just wanted to point out that the problem in OP's code is not related to the positive numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another clause that is available when Head is negative:

```
sumPos([Head | Tail], X) :- Head =< 0, sumPos(Tail, X).
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got an answer but you can just use arithmetic to achieve the same without the if-then-else. Instead of:

```
X is N+Head
```

use:

```
X is N + max(Head, 0)
```

Here is your re-written predicate:

```
sumPos([] ,0).
sumPos([Head | Tail], X) :-
    sumPos(Tail, N), 
    X is N + max(Head, 0).
```

and here is your test:

```
?- sumPos([1,-2,3,-5], X).
X = 4.
```

Exercise: measure which implementation is faster in different Prologs, using different compilation flags, if available. How can you explain your results?